# Is it possible to register a click on an element excluding nested elements in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, click

I have the following HTML:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="some">               
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <div data-role="panel" id="panel">
      <p>I'm a panel</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I need to fire a function if the user clicks on the page, but not if he clicks on the panel.

Is this possible = registering a click on an element excluding some of it's children? I'm currently trying like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 $('div:jqmData(role="page"):not(#panel)').live('click tap', function(event) {
    console.log("registered a click");
    // fire a function
    });
```

Comment: From the jQuery .live() documentation: "Chaining methods is not supported. For example, $("a").find(".offsite, .external").live( ... ); is not valid and does not work as expected". Also: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the `event.target` object against a selector.
Use [`.parentsUntil(<elementTostopAt>, <selector>)`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) to traverse up the tree, to make sure that we did not click on a child of the forbidden element. To include the clicked element, use [`.andSelf()`](http://api,jquery.com/andSelf/).

The previously described methods return a jQuery collection of elements. Check the size of this property using `.length`. If the size is non-zero, `return`.

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('click tap', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).parentsUntil(this, '#panel').andSelf().length) return;
    console.log("registered a click");
    // fire a function
});
```

Comment: @frequent I originally changed `.live` to `.on`. Then, I realized that you're using jQuery mobile, and undid the change. The method to filter is still the same, though.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. One more question: is parentsUntil better than closest?

Comment: @frequent You can't specify where to stop matching in [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). It only stops when it has reached the root element, or if a match is found. You can use `parentsUntil` to stop early, by using the `:first` postfix at the selector. I've forgot to add that to my answer, though.